# Netplan on Ubuntu 18.10 (Cosmic Cuttlefish): DHCP4 + static routes

Tags: networking, configuration, dhcp, routing, netplan

I'm using fresh Ubuntu Server 18.10 (Cosmic) installation with netplan.
What I'm trying to achieve is to setup network interface via DHCP and add some static routes.

With static IP settings things are working correctly.
With DHCP 'routes:' are not applied

Any ideas how to change that?

Commands used to apply settings:

```
netplan generate
netplan apply
```

**WORKS**

```
network:
 ethernets:

  enp0s3:
   addresses: []
   dhcp4: true
   dhcp6: true

  enp0s8:
   dhcp4: false
   addresses:
     - 192.168.1.10/24
   routes:
    - to: 10.10.0.0/24
      via: 192.168.1.2
    - to: 10.9.0.0/24
      via: 192.168.1.2
 version: 2
```

**DOES NOT WORK**

```
network:
 ethernets:

  enp0s3:
   addresses: []
   dhcp4: true
   dhcp6: true

  enp0s8:
   dhcp4: true           # <- CHANGED
   addresses: []         # <- CHANGED
   routes:
    - to: 10.10.0.0/24
      via: 192.168.1.2
    - to: 10.9.0.0/24
      via: 192.168.1.2
 version: 2
```

**EDIT: [20.12.2018]:** After new research I was able to find that my issue is an animal (a bug to be specific).

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan/+bug/1781652
- https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/1850

Comment: Should this `addresses: []` be there?

Comment: I have tried with this line removed as well, no change.

Comment: Please run it with `sudo netplan --debug apply` and post the specific errors!

Comment: Nothing interesting. Just, same, configuration but formatted differently + not informations not related with subject. (I can't paste log here, it's just too long).

Comment: After new research I was able to find that my issue is an animal (a bug to be specific). * bugs.launchpad.net/netplan/+bug/1781652 * github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/1850

Answer (score 1):

After new research I was able to find that my issue is an animal (a bug to be specific).

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan/+bug/1781652
- https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/1850

Routes are applied before DHCP, which destroys them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this... (*keep the indentation and spacing as it is*)...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: true
      addresses: []
    enp0s8:
      dhcp4: true
      addresses: []
      routes:
        - to: 10.10.0.0/24
          via: 192.168.1.2
        - to: 10.9.0.0/24
          via: 192.168.1.2
```

Then...

`sudo netplan --debug generate` # generate config files

`sudo netplan apply` # apply configuration

`reboot` # reboot and confirm proper operation

**Update #1:**

Because of the bugs that you found, try this...

Name the only existing .yaml file as `01-dhcp.yaml` and include this text...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: true
      addresses: []
    enp0s8:
      dhcp4: true
      addresses: []
      gateway4: 10.x.x.1 <-adjust this address for your environment
      optional: true     <-don't wait for connection, try with/without this
```

Then create a second .yaml file called `02-routes.yaml` with this text...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s8:
      dhcp4: false   <-disable dhcp this time around
      addresses: []  <-this MAY need to be removed
      routes:
        - to: 10.10.0.0/24
          via: 192.168.1.2
        - to: 10.9.0.0/24
          via: 192.168.1.2
```

`sudo netplan --debug generate` # generate config files

`sudo netplan apply` # apply configuration

`reboot` # reboot and confirm proper operation

Comment: FYI, it's not just the indentation but also the spacing between elements as well.  (Even if you keep indentation lined up extra line spaces will mess with it)

Comment: After new research I was able to find that my issue is an animal (a bug to be specific).

* https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan/+bug/1781652

* https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/1850

Comment: @felixd see Update #1 in my answer. It may require slight tweaking, but the idea is to set routes AFTER the dhcp has hopefully completed. Report backk to "@heynnema"

Comment: @heynnema this does not work...configs from different files are merged (repeated fields are overwritten)

Comment: @felixd then I guess that you're stuck with assigning a static address.

Comment: @heynnema Well there are workarounds [disabling netplan]...but ...then why netplan was created? :)

Comment: @felixd netplan was created primarily for servers. For the rest of us, it's a PITA. And yes, if you run a GUI, NetworkManager might be an alternative option. Do you need the .yaml file to use NetworkManager instead?

Comment: @heynnema it's for my VMs (settings). Relax ;) I will just solve it by setting proper DHCPd, but still this tool, right now just sucks.